# Insert Into Temp Table from another Temp Table throws error

Tags: sql, t-sql, temp-tables

I've seen a few of the questions and answers for this, but they all seem different than my problem. I am trying to insert into a temp table with a where clause from a real table to the id on a different temp table. Let me explain

Here is my first insert. It creates a temp table based on the parameters

```
Insert Into #programs (programs_id, state_program_ID, org_no, bldg_no)
    Select programs_ID, state_program_ID, org_no, bldg_no
    From programs as p
    Where p.org_no = @org_no
        And p.bldg_no = @bldg_no
        And p.school_yr = @school_year
```

This returns a table that has a flat list of programs. Programs are offered at the school level and are slightly modified from the related `state_program`.

Then I need a list of all students that have taken the program from the `program_student` table.

```
Insert Into #programStudent (programs_id , ss_id, status_id)
    Select ps.programs_id, ps.ss_id, ps.status_id
    From program_student as ps
    Where ps.programs_id = #programs.program_id 
        --'#programs.program_id' throws error
```

This would meet my need having all students that have taken any of the programs offered by the school at that school year.

The full error is

> The multi-part identifier '#programs.program_id' could not be bound.

Comment: does it matter that in one place it says `proram_Id`, not `programs_id` ? Consistent names for database table attributes is a must.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not addressing the #programs table in your second query. that last line will have to change to something like this:

```
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM #Programs WHERE #Programs.programs_id = ps.program_id)
```

This is how you must address temp tables - they do not become variables in your current script - they are actual tables which get cleaned up after you disconnect. As such, they need to be introduced as tables - in a from clause, for each query that needs to reference them.

Comment: Begging your pardon, but what is the benefit to using `exists ( select top 1 1 from ...` (without an `ORDER BY` clause for the `TOP`) instead of `exists ( select 42 from ...`? A small test resulted in the same execution plan for all three options: `TOP`, `TOP` with `ORDER BY` and `42`.

Comment: @JaazCole I'm sure this is the right answer, but I'm not sure what this is doing. Mainly the `Exists` and `Select TOP 1 1` are confusing to me

Comment: @HABO: There is no need for an order by if all you are checking for is existence. If this was a situation with a cross apply where I wanted the latest record for some reason, that would necessitate an order by.
@christopher-clark: TOP stops execution after the following number of rows is returned. thus, TOP 1 stops execution once 1 row is returned. Since we aren't returning any data, selecting a constant (1) is preferable. Thus, `EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM...`

Comment: @JaazCole `EXISTS` tells the query optimizer to ignore the column list, i.e. `42` or `*` are ignored equally, and to terminate when any row is found. `TOP` provides no benefit in this case.

Comment: @HABO right, I'd forgotten that apparently. thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 0):

You had a typo when defining the `#programs` table - you called the column `programs_id` and not `program_id`. Just fix it, and you should be fine:

```
Insert Into #programs (program_id, state_program_ID, org_no, bldg_no)
-- "s" removed Here ---------^
    Select programs_ID, state_program_ID, org_no, bldg_no
    From programs as p
    Where p.org_no = @org_no
        And p.bldg_no = @bldg_no
        And p.school_yr = @school_year
```

Comment: Unfortunately not! I didn't do a good job of copying it over. Edited my question